# How to filter lines with a filter chain

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose you have a text file, say `list.txt`, like this:

```
# Category 1
foobar

# Category 2
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3

# Category 3
foobar.dummy
foobar.dummy
```

And you have a bash script, say, `list.sh`, to extract lines from `list.txt`. The script takes one or more patterns to filter the text file with grep. Conceptually, it will be something like this from commandline:

```
cat list.txt | grep filter1 | grep fitler1 | ... | grep filtern
```

However, the problem is that the number of filters varies, so that you have to use a loop to do the filtering. For the loop, I am hoping something like below would work.

```
filters=$*
for filter in ${filters[@]}; do
    result=`ad_hoc_show $result | grep $filter`
done

ad_hoc_show $result # should maintain original line structure
```

For example, below is desired output.

```
$ list.sh foobar
foobar
foobar.dummy
foobar.dummy

$ list.sh dummy \d
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3
```

So, any advice on how to implement the `ad_hoc_show` function?

Comment: `filters=$*` does not get you an array and messes up arguments with spaces. Don't do that. Just use `for filter in "$@"; do` (or even just `for filter; do`) to loop over all arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `grep` supports `-P` then you can use this function:

```
filt() {
   re=$(printf "(?=.*?%s)" "$@")
   grep -P "$re" list.txt
}

filt 'dummy' '\d'
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3

filt 'foobar'
foobar
foobar.dummy
foobar.dummy
```

---

**UPDATE:** In case `grep -P` is not available then you can use `awk`:

```
filt() { re=$(printf "/%s/&&" "$@"); awk "${re:0: -2}" list.txt; }

filt 'dummy' '[0-9]'
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3

filt 'foobar'
foobar
foobar.dummy
foobar.dummy
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh

ad_hoc_show() {
    filter=$1
    shift

    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        grep "$filter"
        return
    fi

    grep "$filter" | ad_hoc_show "$@"
}

file=$1
shift
ad_hoc_show "$@" <"$file"
```

As David C. Rankin points out in his comment:

For `bash` it is possible to avoid unnecessary sub-shells by replacing

```
grep "$filter" | ad_hoc_show "$@"
```

with

```
ad_hoc_show "$@" <<<"$(grep "$filter")"
```

in the recursive call.

And you could avoid using `shift` by using offset array indexing (I don't know if there's an official term for this) by using `"${@:2}" in the`ad_hoc_show`calls and removing the`shift` lines.

Comment: Good solution. You can eliminate spawning subshells with `ad_hoc_show "$@" <"$file"` on the call, and `ad_hoc_show "$@" <<<$(grep "$filter")` within the function. Any downside to eliminating `shift` and indexing the arguments with `"${@:2}"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The file redirection is a good idea. Using command substitution instead of the pipes is more questionable since `<<<` is a bash-ism and the original is `sh`-safe I believe. I can't think of a reason to not use `"${@:2}"` in place of shift other than I think more people are familiar with shift.